# Do python Objects also store their memory address?

Tags: object-oriented, python

In python documentation, I found that every object has a type, identity, and value.

Does this mean that the object also contains/stores their memory address??

Or are they just created at some memory location containing/storing the type and its value?

To me, the 2nd definition makes more sense although theoretically, we say that they also have an identity. It is totally up to the Python memory manager to allocate/deallocate
space for the object

Thank you so much
Chyanit

Answer (score 2):

It is a documented implementation detail of CPython, that the identity of an object **is** it's memory address. Other implementations vary, e.g. Jython and IronPython have GCs that move (some) objects during their lifetime, but the identity is fixed when it is created.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "memory address" in Python, therefore, the object *cannot* store it.

There may or may not be a concept of memory address in a particular *implementation* of Python, though, but that is *not* a part of Python, that is a private internal implementation detail of that particular implementation.

For example, Jython is written in Java, and Java doesn't have a concept of "memory" or "memory address", therefore, Jython *cannot possibly* have a concept of "memory address".

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I got it now the object does not store the memory address. It simply contains the type and an internal state(data). It gets created at a particular location in Cpython but does not store that information